# Strategies for Building a Strong Client Base on Upwork: Insights Needed!

Tags: freelance-websites, difficult-client, freelance

I am a C++ developer, and I'm seeking advice on building a client base on Upwork. Could you share your experiences and provide tips on effectively attracting clients? I'm interested in strategies for promoting my profile, creating compelling proposals, and any insights you might have. Your personal experiences and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There might be some useful info on Reddit r\upwork